# How do I retrieve attributes on properties in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, properties

I am trying to implement a simple API where a user can dictate the sorting of object properties with a property attribute.

Something like:

```
[Sorting(SortOrder=0)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

In the basic ToString() method, I then use reflection to pull the properties from the object.

```
Type currentType = this.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfoArray = currentType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
Array.Sort(propertyInfoArray, this.comparer);
```

I have written a custom class using the IComparer interface to do the Array.Sort, but once I'm in there I get stuck trying to retrieve the [Sorting] attribute.  I currently have something that looks like this:

```
PropertyInfo xInfo = (PropertyInfo)x;
PropertyInfo yInfo = (PropertyInfo)y;
```

I thought I could use xInfo.Attributes, but the PropertyAttributes class does not do what I need it to do.  Does anyone have any guidance for how to retrieve that [Sorting] Attribute?  I have looked around a lot, but with how overloaded the word Attribute is in programming I keep getting a lot of false leads and dead ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx)

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(Student).GetMembers()
                                                   .First(p => p.Name== "Id");
object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Edit:

To get the value itself, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630348/custom-attributes-on-class-members/630424#630424).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(MyClass);
object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Comment: This retrieves any custom attributes on a class, not the SortingAttribute on a property.

Comment: Right you are, same idea though...propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(boolean);

Answer (score 1):

[GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx) is the method you will want to use.

```
SortingAttribute[] xAttributes = (SortingAttribute[])xInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SortingAttribute), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use a set of extension methods for this:

```
public TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider, bool inherit = false)
  where TAttribute : Attribute
{
  return GetAttributes<TAttribute>(provider, inherit).FirstOrDefault();
}

public IEnumerable<TAttribute> GetAttributes<TAttribute>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider, bool inherit = false)
  where TAttribute : Attribute
{
  return provider.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherit).Cast<TAttribute>()
}
```

I can call it as:

```
var attrib = prop.GetAttribute<SortingAttribute>(false);
```

From a design point of view though, I would ensure that you only inspect these properties as reflection isn't always quick. If you are comparing multiple objects, you may find the use of reflection to be a bit of a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GetCustomAttributes` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fetch the attribute using [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on the `PropertyInfo` instance.