# Is it possible to get the properties and associated attributes of an object?

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, properties, attributes

Is it possible to get the properties and their associated attributes as a collection or property set?

The properties of the object I'm looking at have attributes for use in JSON.NET, and I'd like to find out what they all are. Afterwards, I'll try to find out which of them are not null.

Here's a sample object:

```
[JsonObject]
    public class Conditions
    {
        [JsonProperty("opened_since")]
        public DateTime? OpenedSince { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("added_until")]
        public DateTime? AddedUntil { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("opened_until")]
        public DateTime? OpenedUntil { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("archived_until")]
        public DateTime? ArchivedUntil { get; set;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean like `Conditions c; PropertiesInfo infos = c.GetType().GetProperties();` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you all the properties, their attributes and the values of the arguments for the attributes (note this solution assumes you are using .net framework version 4.5):

```
PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property: " + prop.Name);
    foreach (CustomAttributeData att in prop.CustomAttributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tAttribute: " + att.AttributeType.Name);
        foreach (CustomAttributeTypedArgument arg in att.ConstructorArguments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + arg.ArgumentType.Name + ": " + arg.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Property: OpenedSince
        Attribute: JsonPropertyAttribute
                String: opened_since
Property: AddedUntil
        Attribute: JsonPropertyAttribute
                String: added_until
Property: OpenedUntil
        Attribute: JsonPropertyAttribute
                String: opened_until
Property: ArchivedUntil
        Attribute: JsonPropertyAttribute
                String: archived_until
```

Comment: Fyi, we have to user NamedArguements instead of att.ConstructorArguments if the attributes is set like  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "opened_since"]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static Hashtable ConvertPropertiesAndValuesToHashtable(this object obj)
    {
        var ht = new Hashtable();

        // get all public static properties of obj type
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos =
            obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(a => a.MemberType.Equals(MemberTypes.Property)).ToArray();
        // sort properties by name
        Array.Sort(propertyInfos, (propertyInfo1, propertyInfo2) => propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name));

        // write property names
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            ht.Add(propertyInfo.Name,
                   propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, BindingFlags.Public, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
        }

        return ht;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't get the attributes of the property though.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer after reading Chris' answer above and [Marc Gravell's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630410/24391)

I created this function to do it for me:

```
    public HastTable BuildRequestFromConditions(Conditions conditions)
    {
        var ht = new HashTable();
        var properties = conditions.GetType().GetProperties().Where(a => a.MemberType.Equals(MemberTypes.Property) && a.GetValue(conditions) != null);
        properties.ForEach(property => 
            {
                var attribute = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute));
                var castAttribute = (JsonPropertyAttribute)attribute;

                ht.Add(castAttribute.PropertyName, property.GetValue(conditions));
            });
        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? If I understand right, you need all the properties of the class that are decorated by an attribute. I didn't want to include JSON.NET reference, so have used `XmlText` attribute instead.

```
    [Test]
    public void dummy()
    {
        var conditions = new Conditions();

        var propertyInfos = conditions.GetType().GetProperties();
        propertyInfos.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var attrs = x.GetCustomAttributes(true);
                if (attrs.Any(p => p.GetType() == typeof(XmlTextAttribute)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, attrs.Aggregate((o, o1) => string.Format("{0},{1}",o,o1)));
                }
            });
    }
```

And the class looks like this -

```
[XmlType]
public class Conditions
{
    [XmlText]
    public DateTime? OpenedSince { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public DateTime? AddedUntil { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public DateTime? OpenedUntil { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public DateTime? ArchivedUntil { get; set; }

    public string NotTobeListed { get; set; }
}
```

Console Output:

```
System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] OpenedSince System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute
System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] AddedUntil System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute
System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] OpenedUntil System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute
System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] ArchivedUntil System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute
```

Note that `NotToBeListed` doesn't show up.

Comment: That shouldn't be too difficult, have updated my answer with one way of doing it. Could do with some refactor.